# IIS URL rewrite for multiple slashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis-7

I am having problem to rewrite a url that may or may not include a secondary pattern.

This is a rewrite mod for a login system.
I want to rewrite
"contoso.com/register/1/"
and
"contoso.com/register/2/{key}"

However, I found that if I have

```
^register/([1-2]+).*
```

I am not going to get the key for step 2 of the registration.

And if I use

```
^register/([1-2]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+).*
```

for my mask. It is not going to rewrite "contoso.com/register/1/" .

Will it be possible to rewrite in just one rule? Or I must have two separate rules for this scenario?

It will be good to help with the IIS presentation. But if you know the method on .htaccess. I am also able to convert myself. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research on Regex and found that a /* mask will make the rule work while it excludes "/" being detected.
The mask I am having now is

```
^register/([1-2]+)/*([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)
```

Which will take step 1 as {R:1} and key after slash as {R:2}